# Как можно убрать :hover у элемента через JS или CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть кнопка, у которой есть :hover со сменой цветов. Когда кнопка недоступна через атрибуты disable нужно сделать чтобы :hover эффекта не было

Я пробовал через

```
cursor: none
```

Но :hover всё равно срабатывал

Answer (score 5):

Примените два класса к соответствующему элементу. Один содержит поведение при наведении, а другой содержит все остальные стили.
Вот метод, позволяющий удалить класс с поведением при наведении реализованный на `jQuery`:

```
$(element).removeClass('hover');
```

Вот реализация этих же действий на нативном `JS`:

```
element.classList.remove('hover'); //element это уже полученный узел DOM
```

Comment: Вoпросы с меткой `[javascript]` но без метки какой-либо библиотеки (и без явного контекста ее использования) предполагают ответы на чистом JavaScript'e. Это имеет значение, т.к. метки тематические: они помогают участникам находить именно те ответы, которые нужны. Конечно, в случаях когда сторонняя библиотека сама по себе является решением - уместно предлагать, но в данном случае стандартных возможностей достаточно: `element.classList.remove('hover');`. Прошу отнестись с пониманием и учитывать тематику вопросов.

Answer (score 5):

Для этого есть псевдокласс [:not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:not) :

```css
button:not([disabled]):hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button>Кнопка</button> <button disabled>Кнопка не доступная</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Несколько проще и быстрее будет через `CSS` таким образом, при наведение на все элементы которые не `disabled` будет срабатывать `cursor: pointer`

```
.btn:not([disabled]):hover{
  cursor: pointer
}
```